# Nicer way to resolve as a whole an object that has promised attributes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm creating a json object as the response in a node.js service; and some of its fields are calculated asynchronously and wrapped in promises.

Is there any elegant way to compose a promise that is resolved when all the attributes are resolved? (rather than doing an `all` on the values explicitly and replacing them).

So instead of doing something like:

```
function calculateResponse() {
  var obj = {
    a : somePromise(),
    b : someOtherPromise()
  };
  return q.all([obj.a, obj.b]).then(function(results) {
    obj.a = results[0];
    obj.b = results[1];
    return obj;
  });
}
```

It'd be good to have something like:

```
function calculateResponse() {
  var obj = {
    a : somePromise(),
    b : someOtherPromise()
  };
  return q.allFields(obj);
}
```

Comment: WHat are you trying to gain...a reusable wrapper for `q.all()` that builds the array and loops through object and results?

Comment: yeah, basically that's what I want; and I'd rather not write it myself if there's a standard way to do it already ^_^

Comment: There is no standard implementation for what you're asking.  You write a small loop yourself to gather the properties that are promises and then call `q.all()` with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I am doing it now, just in case nobody comes out with a better solution:

```
var allAttributesResolved = function(obj) {
    var pairs = _(obj).pairs().unzip().value();
    var keys = pairs[0];
    var values = pairs[1];

    return q.all(values).then(function(results) {
        return _.zipObject(keys, results);
    });
};
```

If using `bluebird` rather than `q` there is a method called [`props`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#props---promise) that does just the same.

Comment: Why are you using the underscore library when that is not mentioned in the question at all?  And, you don't even refer to it.

Comment: It's the bread and butter of JS programming, I don't see why I should explicitly state the obvious

Comment: That's your personal opinion.  Far more people do NOT use that library than do use it so "bread and butter" is certainly not actually the case.  It is a custom here (and you've been around here far long enough to know this) that you don't offer solutions based on third party libraries that were not requested or tagged in the question except in special circumstances in which case you call out the reason you're using a third party library and explain that.  In this case, there is no particular reason to require underscore for this solution.

Comment: lodash is the most depended library in the npm package repository, just saying...